# Mule threading profile and threadWaitTimeout

Tags: multithreading, mule

While I am reading Mule Threading profile I came across `threadWaitTimeout` for which Mule doc says:

`How long to wait in milliseconds when the pool exhausted action is WAIT. If the value is negative, it will wait indefinitely`, at one place

and

`How long to wait for a thread to become available`, at another place.

What will happen

- If Receiver's threading profile is set to include `threadWaitTimeout=1000`
- If Flow's threading profile is set to include `threadWaitTimeout=1000`
- If Dispatcher's threading profile is set to include `threadWaitTimeout=1000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receiver, flow and dispatcher are three different thread pools:

[image: threadpools]

The receiver use threads, the flow use threads and the dispatcher use threads. Each one at a different stage of the execution. To understand it better I would recommend to read both the [docs](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tuning+Performance) you mention and the fine tuning chapter of [Mule In Action](http://www.manning.com/dossot2/) 2ed.